# My minecraft server is running but i can't connect to it

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, server-administration

So i just started my own server and i tried to connect to it with localhost and with my ip. But it doesn't work and it won't let me connect to my own server and it always said that i'm disconnected. I'm running my server on CMD.

```
[09:49:59 INFO]: Starting minecraft server version 1.12.2
[09:49:59 INFO]: Loading properties
[09:49:59 INFO]: Default game type: SURVIVAL
[09:49:59 INFO]: Generating keypair
[09:49:59 INFO]: Starting Minecraft server on *:25573
[09:49:59 INFO]: Using default channel type
[09:50:00 INFO]: Preparing level "world"
[09:50:01 INFO]: Loaded 488 advancements
[09:50:01 INFO]: Preparing start region for level 0
[09:50:02 INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 7%
[09:50:03 INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 38%
[09:50:04 INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 75%
[09:50:04 INFO]: Done (3.821s)! For help, type "help" or "?"
```

Comment: What is the specific error you are getting from the server when you try to connect?

Answer (score 2):

This may be a simple one... but see my comment to your question anyway.

Your startup indicates your port number is 25573. This is not the default for minecraft, so you will need to use 127.0.0.1:25573 or 'IPaddress':25573 to connect.